# Forloop not initializing the 2nd time despite initializing the 1st time when parsing the same text file

Tags: python, file

I am trying to parse through a text file twice, but the second for loop won't work despite it being the same code as the previous. Does anyone know why? I've been staring at this code for quite some time already. So thanks in advance!

My main basis of the code would be that the code first retrieves the unique dates in the 1st for loop and then uses the unique date in the 2nd for loop to find the total cash paid on each unique date.

[Note: I have placed print statements for debugging purposes.]

Here are 3 lines as formatted in 'transactions.txt', each separated by a **tab**:

25-03-2016  McDonalds   $21.30
09-12-2016  KFC $59.43
08-01-2017  BurgerKing  $47.56

**Input Code**

```
with open('transactions-output-2.txt','w') as out_file:

    with open('transactions.txt', 'r') as in_file:

        unique_dates = []

        for row in in_file:
            line = row.strip('\n').split('\t')

            date = line[0]

            if date not in date_list:
                unique_dates.append(date)


        for ref_date in unique_dates:
            print(ref_date)

            for row in in_file:
                line = row.strip('\n').split('\t')
                print(line[0])
```

**Output Code**

```
25-03-2016
09-12-2016
08-01-2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only iterate through the opened file once per `open()`. This is because the `in_file` object is in iterator that is exhausted when the first for-loop runs.

To avoid it you can read the file into a list before processing it:

```
with open('transactions-output-2.txt','w') as out_file:

    with open('transactions.txt', 'r') as in_file:
        file_lines = in_file.readlines()
        unique_dates = []

        for row in file_lines:
            line = row.strip('\n').split('\t')

            date = line[0]

            if date not in date_list:
                unique_dates.append(date)


        for ref_date in unique_dates:
            print(ref_date)

            for row in file_lines:
                line = row.strip('\n').split('\t')
                print(line[0])
```